# Is there a one-to-one relation between photons and electrons in bremsstrahlung?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, x-rays

I think I crammed the whole question in the title:

Is it correct to assume that **one** decelerated electron is responsible for the emission of **one** photon?

Answer (score 4):

Not quite. One *interaction* between one electron and one charge is responsible for the emission of one photon. One electron may interact with multiple charges in sequence, dissipating part of its kinetic energy as a new photon in each interaction.

Comment: There are exceptions.  Consider an electron which causes a bound electron to jump several orbital levels.  That bound electron will "cascade" down to ground state by emitting a sequence of photons.  But that is not photon emission from the high-speed "free" electron, I agree.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft at lieast in "german school nomenclature", that's not considered bremsstrahlung but characteristical radiation.

Comment: Interesting answer, is it possible to go somewhat deeper without immediately touching the gory quantum mechanic details?

Comment: @Jasper I agree; just wanted to point out there are other mechanisms which can put noise in your data

Comment: @Jasper I deleted my earlier comments because I think my attempt to explain was more bad than good. Instead I would just suggest reading the wikipedia article for bremsstrahlung.